# Kafka Stream KTable delay

Tags: apache-kafka

As far as I know, Kafka Stream process the messages "as soon as it arrives". But when I use Kafka Stream for processing KTable (e.g. word count example on [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html), it has some delay (up to seconds) to group and show the word count to output topic.
Is this normal or any other configuration that I need to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set `commit.interval.ms = 0`, Kafka Stream will commit the offset as soon as possible.

Note, if `processing.guarantee` is set to `exactly_once`, the default value is 100, otherwise the default value is 30000 ms.

From the official Kafka Streams docs - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#streamsconfigs